# How to have sound on objective-c while volume is off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, volume

i have to play a sound when an uibutton is clicked. My problem is that when device is with volume down, so user pull down volume in hw way, my sound will have volume down. Is there a possibility to have my sound with max volume though volume is down? I hope my answer is well formed

Comment: Do you know why people turn down the volume on their devices?  It's because they don't want to hear sounds from your app or anybody else's.  Respect their choice!

Comment: of course.. but if user don't want to play sound, don't click on button! :) i don't want to develop an app that play sound on startup with or without volume set to down :)

Comment: @JackTurky if the user wants to use your app AND be silent? That's what the silence option is for, it's a good thing that the system stops you from making sound in silent mode. It's like if it allowed you to network while in flight mode.

Comment: my app use sound to work.. if users can not play sound the app is without any sense :)

Comment: If it requires sound, they will turn their sound up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether this is possible or not, it would be a very bad practice.  Apps should always respect user's choice, including volume.  Think of a user that's using your app in a very quite environment (e.g. hospital, airplane, etc.), so the user turns the volume down - yet your app still makes loud noises.  I'm guessing this would rather alienate the user.

My guess is that normally it's not possible though.  Have a look at this article: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/_index.html - specifically, look for *How do I control playback level?* topic.

Comment: Thanks you! Don't worry, i don't want to develop an app that play sound on startup with or without volume set to down, but user can choose to play sound or not by clicking a button :) I will see that article

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you can configure the audio session parameters but there are behaviours that the system will not let you change (when the user receives a call or silences the device for example). The system will send you notifications so you can react gracefully but as others have said, when users silence their device it should be silent, no matter what the developpers want (especially with tons of apps running in the background...).